# When I render my model it becomes transparent

Tags: modeling, eevee-render-engine

[image]

In the Material Preview, it looks like this
[image]

when I go to render this weird happens
[image]

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tjqqAinC3HoIV1km4lqlH4qZgK7uvvQN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please add your blend file to your question.  ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Might have checked *holdout*

Comment: yes it looks like it's the Holdout option that is enabled for the collection, check the Outliner

Comment: @moonboots Holdout was never enabled.

Comment: weird because it works fine here

Comment: @moonboots so wait, you loaded the blend file and it renders fine?

Comment: yes no problem for me (and Holdout was not enabled as you said)

Comment: guess my blender installation is broken? I tested with the default cube and it does the same thing.

Comment: do you have an AMD graphic card? In that case try the previous driver version

Comment: @moonboots I reinstalled Blender and its working now, thanks for the help dude :)

Comment: ok so it was not an AMD + driver problem?